# Creating SQL Queries Dynamically in Scala and Apache Spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, subquery, apache-spark-sql

I am having two tables TableA and TableB with below structure

### Table1

```
PkCol1
PkCol2
Col3
Col4
Col5
```

### Table2

```
PkCol1
PkCol2
Col3
Col4
Col5
```

But i am getting the primary key information as input. For example, i receive it as PkCol2,PkCol2.  I may receive more primaryKey columns as input too.

How do i dynamically add my where condition to spark sql ?

Below is my code

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("Table1")
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("Table2")
primaryKeyString = ar(1)

val df3 = spark.sql("Select * from table1 where "+primaryKeyString+" not in (select "+primaryKeyString+" from table2)").toDF()
```

If there is a better way to do it with Dataframes let me know.

I am able to acheive my purpose by concatenating in spark sql as below

```
val df3 = spark.sql("Select * from table1 where CONCAT("+primaryKeyString+") not in (select CONCAT("+primaryKeyString+") from table2)").toDF()
```

Trying to find if there is a better way to achieve it in scala.